# iOS Can I inject HTML code in the emails send by mail app?

Tags: iphone, ios, email

We are running an stationery business and designing email stationeries, signatures etc for people. On PC there's no problem using those because it's easy to add HTML to the email contents in most of the mail clients. However, is this  possible with iOS?

How are we doing that now for mobile devices is we tell users to add our SMTP server and send messages through it. How this SMTP works is it's  wrapping each email with HTML before sending. I wonder if this can be done directly in iPhone with some kind of post-processing of emails before those are sent?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AFAIK you can't trap emails sent from the built in email client.  You can however, write your own app that sends emails with HTML using the `MFMailComposeViewController`.

EDIT: Added some example code:

```
- (void) sendEventInEmail
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"Email Subject"];

    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *iTunesLink = @"http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/whats-on-reading/id347859140?mt=8"; // Link to iTune App link
    NSString *content = [eventDictionary objectForKey:@"Description"];
    NSString *imageURL = [eventDictionary objectForKey:@"Image URL"];
    NSString *findOutMoreURL = [eventDictionary objectForKey:@"Link"];

    NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<br /> <a href = '%@'> <img src='%@' align=left  style='margin:5px' /> </a> <b>%@</b> <br /><br />%@ <br /><br />Sent using <a href = '%@'>What's On Reading</a> for the iPhone.</p>", findOutMoreURL, imageURL, emailSubject, content, iTunesLink];

    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

[picker release];
    }

 - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
    {
        // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
        switch (result)
        {
            case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
                break;
            case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
                break;
            case MFMailComposeResultSent:
                break;
            case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It should look somewhat like this:

```
    // Compose body
    NSMutableString *emailBody = [[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"<html><body>"] autorelease];
    [emailBody appendString:@"<p>Hi<br><br>THis is some HTML</p>"];        
    [emailBody appendString:@"</body></html>"];

    // Compose dialog
    MFMailComposeViewController *emailDialog = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    emailDialog.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [emailDialog setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"test@test.com"]];

    // Set subject
    [emailDialog setSubject:@"I got a question!"];

    // Set body
    [emailDialog setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

    // Show mail
    [self presentModalViewController:emailDialog animated:YES];
    [emailDialog release];
```

As said above, don't forget the delegate 8)

HTH
Marcus

Answer (score 0):

Using MFMailComposeViewController you can include HTML in the body of the email. Additionally, you can attach images. See these methods:

`- (void)setMessageBody:(NSString*)body isHTML:(BOOL)isHTML`
`- (void)addAttachmentData:(NSData*)attachment mimeType:(NSString*)mimeType fileName:(NSString*)filename`

Answer (score 0):

You can take the body text of their email and change it (by using `stringWithFormat:` or even an NSMutableString) to make it html. Using MFMailComposeViewController's `-(void)setMessageBody:(NSString*)body isHTML:(BOOL)isHTML`

Example:

```
 NSString *bodyText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<html><p>%@</p></html", bodyField.text];  //Not an HTML expert
```

then send the email with the body being bodyText.